# Adding all the rows of same year using SQL Query instead of php code

Tags: mysql

I am attaching an image to make my question clear.

[image]

I have defined the sections with respect to year, I want that rows of each year should be added to make one row for each year.

For example for Ano 2009 or year 2009, there will be one row, and all of Mes, S, N, O and Total will be the sum of all rows of 2009. Similarly for 2010 and vice versa, so total there will be 3 rows for three years having Ano, Mes, S, N, O and Total.

I can do it programmaticaly using php, but I want to do it using MySQL SQl query. Can anybody help with it?

Comment: Posting the structure of your tables, along with some sample data, would go a long way towards helping anybody answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  Ano,
  Sum(Mes),
  Sum(S),
  Sum(N),
  Sum(O),
  Sum(Total)
from 
  MyTable
Group By Ano
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple group by should do this:

```
SELECT anno,
       sum(mes) as all_mes,
       sum(s) as all_s,
       sum(n) as all_n,
       sum(o) as all_o
FROM your_table
GROUP BY anno;
```

To get the total as an additional column, use a derived table:

```
SELECT t.*, 
       all_mes + all_s + all_n + all_o  as total
FROM ( 
   SELECT anno,
          sum(mes) as all_mes,
          sum(s) as all_s,
          sum(n) as all_n,
          sum(o) as all_o
   FROM your_table
) t
GROUP BY anno;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by the `Ano` but I think you don't want to sum the month...

If you want to see the total for year/month do :

```
select   Ano, Mes,  Sum(S),  Sum(N) ,  Sum(O),  Sum(Total)
from 
  MyTable
Group By Ano, Mes
```

If you want to see the total for year and the numbre of month do :

```
select   ... Count(Mes) ...   Group By Ano
```

If you want to see the total for year do :

```
select   Ano, Sum(S),  Sum(N) ,  Sum(O),  Sum(Total)
from 
  MyTable
Group By Ano
```